# jQuery to write cookie not preserved beyond one page

Tags: jquery, css, session, cookies

I have a little script to remove a mobile stylesheet if a user wants to see the full site.

The CSS link has the ID of #mobile and link a user clicks on has an id #removeStyle

```
$("#removeStyle").click(function () {   
    $('#mobile').remove();
    $.cookie("iWantFullSite", "showFull");
    });

if ($.cookie("iWantFullSite"))
{$('#mobile').remove();}
```

This works great for the page a user is on.  It removes the mobile style sheet. But when the user goes to another page, the mobile site returns.

I'd like the cookie to persist for the session.  Is there something I can add to my script to make this happen?  I'd like to stick with jQuery/JS rather than doing this server side, if possible.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It looks like you're setting the "prefFullSite" cookie, but then checking the "iWantFullSite" cookie.</strike>

From the [docs on Github](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

> By default the path of the
>   cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was created (standard
>   browser behavior). If you want to make it available for instance
>   across the entire domain use path: '/'. Default: path of page where
>   the cookie was created.

Use

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo which isn't in my code.  I've fixed above.

Comment: Do you know of a way to do it without using a plugin?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using the plugin already? I don't think `$.cookie()` is built into basic jQuery.

Comment: I am not - which is why the code above isn't working.  I think I may just use pure JS for this.  Will update.